# Initial value of a "for" loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

In this loop, if v is not pre-defined, how it is assigned the initial value?

```
    for v in birthdays.items():
        print(v)
        break
```

I don't understand the logic. (I was programming with Basic decades ago and new to Python)

Comment: The code just means only the first value of `birthday.items()` will be printed -- is that what you're confused about?

Comment: `v` will take on each value present in `birthdays`.  So the initial value is the first value birthdays.  Unlike basic, you are specifying an integer to step, you are explicitly stepping through the values.

Comment: @StephenRauch Thanks for the comparison. That's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in birthdays.items():
    print(k, v)
```

this is the correct way of iterating through dict items